# MySQL update query on two tables but update only one table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- Table1: group_name, item_name, status
- Table2: group_name, geo

I want to update `table1`. The default status is 0. I want to update the status of `table1` to 1 using a single UPDATE statement.

I want to check for each row in `table1` if the `group_name` exists in `table2`. If so, I will update status to 1.

I tried this but was not able to get the correct result.

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.`STATUS`=1 
WHERE table2.group_name=table1.group_name
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: you are writed UPDATE table1, the WHERE is only a condition and not a command

Comment: the SET is his command...  the actual format is :

Comment: thanks for your comment, i need to learn more ..

Answer (score 3):

You could use a multi-table update as others have shown. But you can also do it in a slightly simpler way with a single table update statement with a subselect:

```
UPDATE table1
SET STATUS = 1 
WHERE group_name IN (SELECT group_name FROM table2)
```

Note also that you don't even need the precondition that `status` in all rows is initially set to zero. You can update all rows to their correct values in a single `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE table1
SET STATUS = group_name IN (SELECT group_name FROM table2)
```

Comment: @MattWestlake: I understand your concern, but I still think this is a valid and useful answer and adds extra value in combination with the other answers. I'm sorry that you felt that my answer should be downvoted, but I think that there can be more than one useful answer to a question and it is quality of this site that a question receives many different answers that show a variety of different solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

you can use multiple update table syntax, so your query would be:

```
UPDATE table1,table2
SET table1.`STATUS`=1 
WHERE table2.group_name=table1.group_name
```

Answer (score 1):

the SET is his command...  the actual format is :
update "tablename"
set "columnname" = 
    "newvalue"
 [,"nextcolumn" = 
   "newvalue2"...]
where "columnname" 
  OPERATOR "value" 
 [and|or "column" 
  OPERATOR "value"];

don't have a SQL database up and running, but I believe the UPDATE command is similar to the FROM command, so i think you have to do

```
UPDATE table1, table2 SET table1.'status' = 1 
WHERE table2.group_name=table1.group_name
```

Comment: Running this gives: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''status' = 1 
WHERE table2.group_name=table1.group_name' at line 1`

Comment: the problem here are the quotes around status. Should be ` instead of '